# how to run web service endpoint class in tomcat or jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, endpoint

I have created webservice using following link
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-eclipse-javase1/section2.html

When i am running a endpoint publish class as java application in eclipse (in my case it is a runservice.java), web service is running fine.

i have created a client for the same webservice client is communicating with webservice properly.

I want to run this endpoint class with jboss or with tomcat without eclipse, it is possible to  do this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the tutorial states that it is a tutorial on how to run a "stand alone webservice application". Since what you are creating is not a java web application but is instead a JavaSE application you will not be able to deploy it to an application server. You will have to create a java web application in order to do that.

[Eclipse WS Tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M3/tutorials/BottomUpWebService.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is possible to deploy this stand alone application " as server, so that i am able to access this from any where

Comment: Of course it is possible to deploy it as a stand alone application since that's what it is. You asked about it deploying it as a web application, which it is not, in JBoss or Tomcat.

Comment: can you help me, i don't know how to do this manually. i am using eclipse and eclipse is deploying this web service, i want to do this myself

Comment: What you have with the IBM tutorial is not meant to be deployed to an application server like Tomcat or JBoss it's meant to run stand alone so all you will have is a jar that you will have to execute from the command line. Have a look at the tutorial in the following link http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/21